# onclick depending on where the view is

Tags: java, android

I want to make something appear depending on where the view is on a tablet for example :
so i know i need to use ontouch listener like this :

```
.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "X :"+event.getX(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

For example there is 2 images from left to right, if i click on the left one, something appear on the right, and if i click on the right one, something will appear.. And i want to extend this to a horizontal scrollview full of images.

Comment: so what problem are you facing?

Comment: How I pass from a simple layout to a complexe layout like a horizontal scrollview

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using onClick().

```
onClick(View v)
{
  int idView= v.getId();
    if(left) // for ex id =2 here
    {
        idView++;
        R.id.idView.setImageBitmap(...); // or whatever u want...
    }
    else
    {  // means right part clicked
        idView--;
        R.id.idView.setImageBitmap(...); // or whatever u want...
    } 
}
```

You need to set some **flags** to check weather **Right** side is clicked or **Left**.
and here you go.